# How is static const different from extern const?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS/Objective C projects, I often have a constants.h file with my API keys and such. Until today, I've been declaring my constants as `static` `const` like so:

```
static NSString * const kAPIKey = @"wembvkejrvb43789gvbiu2bvfake";
```

This works fine, but with the unfortunate downside that I can **only** create constants for primitives and NSString literals, essentially. Other objects, such as UIColor objects, cannot be stored in this constant *as they cannot be initialized with a static literal syntax* (my understanding, citation required).

After reading some C++ docs, I understand a few things:

- The `static` is unnecessary, as `const` are implicitly static.
- Calling `NSString * const x` is actually declaring a constant and immutable value in x. I cannot change the value, but may be able to change what x points to.
- This const has *internal* linkage, meaning the the value is defined right away (presumable at compile time).

Are these conclusions correct?

How does an `extern const` differ? I assume they are externally linked (thus the extern keyword). Are they defined at run time? Can I create some sort of *dynamic* `extern const` that can be set with a value returned by a class method?

For example, I would like to create a globally-scoped constant that contains a UIColor value. I would like to construct this color value using the `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]` class method. This clearly doesn't work with the internally linked constants I've been using (I'm assuming because it happens at compile-time) - but is it possible using an external constant, possibly set up in the `+initialize` method?

Any elaboration on the details of this behavior would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The static is unnecessary, as const are implicitly static.

No, that's not true.

`static` when used at file scope (i.e. outside any method or function) means that the variable is visible only within that file.

`extern` means that the variable is defined in some other file.

`const` means that the variable cannot be modified.

Consider strings. Often, you'll have an implementation file (name ends in .m) that defines some constant string pointer:

```
NSString *const SomeString = @"some string";
```

You might want to use that same constant from other files. If so, you could add a declaration to the header (name ends in .h) file that explains to the compiler that the variable is defined elsewhere:

```
extern NSString *const SomeString;
```

and that would let you use `SomeString` in any file that imports the header file. On the other hand, you might decide that you definitely do *not* want the constant used outside the implementation file. In that case, you could declare it `static` (in the implementation file again):

```
static NSString *const SomeString = @"some string";
```

and that would prevent its use from outside the file.

> Calling `NSString * const x` is actually declaring a constant and immutable value in x. I cannot change the value, but may be able to change what x points to.

Right, it declares the pointer `x` to be constant -- you can't change it. You also can't change the value that it points to if it's actually a `NSString` because an instance `NSString` isn't mutable.

> This const has internal linkage, meaning the the value is defined right away (presumable at compile time).

I'll take the 5th on that -- I'm not sure exactly how the compiler deals with constant strings. I think it's safe to use that as a mental model, though; the string will in any case be defined before your code ever gets to use it.

Comment: If `static` limits scope, and `extern` denotes that the variable is defined elsewhere, I don't even need the `extern` for a global constant? I can use `NSString *const SomeString = @"Some String"` in a header, and access SomeString from any file that imports that header? Put another way, is `extern` required for global constants?

Comment: If you do that (define `SomeString` in the header), you'll get errors about multiple definitions if the header is included in more than one implementation file. `extern` gives you a way to declare the existence of a variable that's defined elsewhere, so that the declaration can be imported into many files but `SomeString` is only *defined* once.

Comment: Very interesting. So my `static const` pattern only worked because I've been declaring them outside of any class in an empty header file, which I then included elsewhere. Must `extern` constants always be defined at compile time using accepted literals, or is there any way to create a 'dynamic' constant (perhaps defined in +initialize).

Comment: A variable declared `extern` doesn't have to be a constant at all. Any variable, `const` or not, can have an `extern` declaration. "Dynamic constant" is a contradiction in terms, and no, there's no way to create one. You could create a regular old global variable and just take care not to change it, but using a class method as @danh suggests is a far better (and much more widely used) solution.

Comment: Ah. And it seems that `const` can only be used at file scope. That certainly answers my questions; there was a **lot** about constants that I simply didn't understand, your answer is one of the best explanations I've read so far.

Answer (score 1):

On your specific programming question, how to create a compile-time defined color object: you can't, because, apart from the handful for which the language supplies literal syntax, objects are created at runtime.

But you can still do it elegantly at runtime, without any addition to global scope, the same way the sdk does...

```
@interface UIColor (RainbowAddition)

+ (UIColor *)chartruseColor;

@end

@implementation UIColor (RainbowAddition)

+ (UIColor *)chartruseColor {
    // bonus: this is really chartruse... according to the internet
    return [self colorWithRed:0.5 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Comment: I certainly understand the logical solution to my problem, thanks for the answer. I'm just trying to understand the underlying reasons. I know that literals (with the exception of container literals) seem to be created at compile time; I just don't understand *why*.

Comment: @cdstamper - its not literals that are created at compile time,but rather objects which can be described by literals.  The reason only those can be created at compile time is that only those can be described to the compiler as a sequence of input tokens (as provided by the language definition which underwent a big improvement in clang 3.6 to include numbers and arrays and dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is a pure extension of C, C++ is not.

At global scope:

- in C (and Objective-C) writing `const` is equivalent to `extern const` (external linkage);
- in C++ writing `const` is equivalent to `static const` (internal linkage).

Both in C (and Objective-C) and C++, to create a global-scoped `const` you can define it, just one time, in one source file like `extern const TYPE identifier = VALUE;` and declare it (typically in an header file) like: `extern const TYPE identifier;` (read it: I defined this const elsewhere at global linkage level).